# Python method not affecting instance of Class

Tags: python

My question is in the `del_node` method, despite setting `self = self.next`, this seems to have no affect on the instance of the class that's making the call.

for instance,
if i have a linked list L = 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4

calling `L.del_node(x)`, where `x` is any node other than the first, 
simply making the call this way will work, however, if I were to call
`L.del_node(1)` I have to call it as `L = L.del_node(1);` I'm assuming this has to do 
with not changing any values of the instance as I am with the others (eg resetting 
`self.data` / `next`, etc).

I ask because I'm confused why the statement `self = self.next` doesn't seem to affect the
instance when `self.data = ...` does.

```
class Node():

    def __init__(self,data = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

    def add_node(self,data):

        if self.data == None:
            self.data = data

        else:
            while self.next != None:
                self = self.next
            self.next = Node(data)


    def del_node(self,data):

        if self.data == None:
            print "ERROR: Null list"
            return self

        elif self.data == data:
            if self.next == None:
                self.data = None
                return self
            else:
                #this seems to be the only case where
                #instance = instance.del_node() matters (why?)
                #opposed to just instance.del_node()
                return self.next

        start = self
        prev = self
        self = self.next

        while self.next != None:
            if self.data == data:
                prev.next = self.next
                return start
            prev = self
            self = self.next

        if self.data == data:
            prev.next = None
            return start
        else:
            print "ERROR: value not in list"
            return start

    def get_len(self):
        length = 0
        if self.data == None:
            return length

        while self.next != None:
            length += 1
            self = self.next
        return length + 1

    def __str__(self):

        string = ''

        while self.next != None:
            string += str(self.data) + ' -> '
            self = self.next
        return string + str(self.data)
```

Comment: If you want to roll your own linked list, you would need to store the start of the list. Also, while you could traverse a list using the self variable, it's bad form - use a different variable name, like currentNode or something. It helps to draw pictures if when you are learning about data structures.

Answer (score 3):

`self = something` does not change the object. Just as everywhere else in Python, it merely rebinds the local name `self`. (There is nothing special to Python about the name `self`--it's only used by convention. A method is just a normal function and `self` is just a normal argument. It's how it's called that passes `self`.)

Comment: isn't the self pointer, a pointer of the instance of the Class making the call?  Regardless, if i reset self.___ = something, i change the instance of the class; however, if i just set self = ____ it seems to have no affect outside the method.  This is whats confusing me.  Hope that made sense, and thanks.

Comment: `self` is the object that the method was called on. The variable `self` doesn't have anything special about it -- it's just like any other local variable. Assigning to it just rebinds the local name.